# удаление элементов со страницы

Tags: javascript, html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]> Есть несколько элементов на странице.Как их удалить ?Удаляет ,но только при нажатии на кнопку и только по одному за раз,а хотелось бы чтобы сразу все элементы.

```
    function deletTable() {
    let text_output = document.getElementById("text-output");
    let table = document.getElementById("arr-table");


    table.parentNode.removeChild(table);

    text_output.remove();
}



 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">QuickSort</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
            aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="homePage.html">Домашняя страница<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="theory.html">Теория</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button"
                   data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Режимы
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Обучение</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Самоконтроль</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Тестовый</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<br>
<div class="block-left">
    <div class="col">
        <br>
        <div class='arr-output'></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="block-right">

    <div class="col">
        <div class="text-output" id="text-output">
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
</div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <button id="next-step" type="button" class="btn btn-light" onclick="next()" value="continue">Следующий
        шаг
    </button>
    <button id="start" type="button" class="btn btn-light" onclick="start()">Начать</button>
    <button id="sd" type="button" class="btn btn-light" onclick="deletTable()">Сбросить</button>

</div>

</body>


</html>

function show(arr, pivot) {  //Вывод массива
let out = '<table class="table table-bordered" id = "arr-table">';
out += `<tr>`;
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {


    if (arr[i] === pivot) {
        out += `<td style="background-color:lightcoral">${arr[i]}</td>`;
        // pivot = "";
    } else if (arr[i] === swapElOne || arr[i] === swapElTwo) {
        out += `<td style="background-color:lightgreen">${arr[i]}</td>`;
        // swapElOne = "";
        // swapElTwo = "";
    } else {
        out += `<td >${arr[i]}</td>`;
    }
}
out += `</tr>`;
out += `</table>`;

$('.arr-output').append(out);
```

}

Comment: а можно увидеть ваш html? какие именно элементы надо удалить не понятно.

Comment: @haswell добавил.Таблица создается динамически при нажатии кнопки шаг

Comment: а что хотите удалять и когда? функцию next() еще покажите

Comment: @haswell удалить надо все таблицы и комментарии к ним.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function deleteAllById(id) {
  var el;
  while (el = document.getElementById(id)) {
    el.parendNode.removeChild(el);
  }
}

function deletTable() {
  deleteAllById("text-output");
  deleteAllById("arr-table");
}
```

или

```
$(".table").remove();
```

Comment: удаляет только text-output.Таблицы не трогаетю

Comment: @ЭдуардФархутдинов я не понял, кто что не трогает?

Comment: я попробовал вашу реализацию . Удаляет только комментарии ,то есть arr-table a таблицы c id arr-table не удаляет

Comment: @ЭдуардФархутдинов В Вашем html нет ни одного элемента с `id="arr-table"`.

Comment: таблица создается динамически ,в методе.

Comment: @ЭдуардФархутдинов То есть Вы этот код не покажете?

Comment: добавил выше.Функция show()

Comment: @ЭдуардФархутдинов, динамически создаваемые элементы не должны иметь один id. Если нужно удалить по кнопке все таблицы сразу, получайте их через класс и в цикле удаляйте.

Comment: @haswell Cannot read property 'removeChild' of undefined.
`deleteAllByСlass("table table-bordered");`
`while (el = document.getElementsByClassName(className)) {
        el.parendNode.removeChild(el);
    }`

Comment: @ЭдуардФархутдинов, нет так не правильно. У вас <div class='arr-output'></div> содержит только таблицы которые надо удалить?

Comment: @haswell Решил.`$(".table").html("");`

Comment: @haswell хотя это не удаляет а просто меняет код.Я сейчас прикреплю скрин выше,как у меня все выглядит

Comment: @ЭдуардФархутдинов, дак вы тогда контейнер у таблиц очисти https://jsfiddle.net/1jvne4kx/ 
Советую все таки внимательно почитать https://learn.javascript.ru/dom-navigation